# setting result's and operand's default value in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

bash 4.2

the equation
`i=$(( (i+1) %3 ))`

I want `left i` to be 0 when the `right i` is wrong input like null.

something like `i=${((i+3) %3):=0}` if I can.

Comment: What do you mean wrong input?

Comment: `right i` can be empty or have trash values

Comment: Then you validate `i` first, and then do the calculation and the assignment.

Comment: I was trying to do the validating by setting the default value thus this question

Comment: No, I don't think that'll work. You should either declare `i` as an integer beforehand (`declare -i i`) so that it can't be assigned trash, or validate its value using a `case` or `[[` command first.

Comment: @Lunartist: What is a _trash value_? If this can be the case, wouldn't it make more sense to validate `i` against a regexp, and issue an error message, instead of silently skipping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try with:

`i=$(( ( ${i-0} + 1) %3 ))`

Comment: it returns `1` on my system

Comment: Because `1%3` is `1`.

Comment: I get it. The title was very misleading. My bad.

Comment: `${i-0}` handles only cases where `i` is not set. For example `i=,; echo $(( ${i-0} ))` results in `bash: , : syntax error` and `i=k; k=7; echo $(( ${i-0} ))` prints `7` (note that we used `i=k`, *not*  `i=$k`. Inside an arithmetic context variables can be full-blown arithmetic expressions, not just numbers)